# Does there exists a non-zero smooth function on Torus, vanishing on an open set such that all its Fourier coefficients are non-zero?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let us identify the torus $\mathbb{T}$ with $[-1,1).$ Does there exists a non-zero $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T})$, vanishing on an open set such that all its Fourier coefficients $a_n$ defined by
$$a_n=\int_\mathbb{T}f(x)e^{inx}dx$$
are non-zero for each $n\in \mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: Huh?  $f\colon \mathbb{T}^1\to\mathbb{T}^1$ with $f(x)=x^2$ has precisely one nonzero Fourier coefficient, and it doesn't vanish on $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid z\bar{z}=1\}$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I deleted that part.